# Time gap between the two colors flashing in Processing

Tags: processing

I have the following program that flashes red and white. There is the possibility of having a time gap every 10 seconds remains stable for seconds in red and then flashes again.

```
  float delay = 1;

    void setup() {
      size(200, 200);
    }


    void draw() { 
      background(96); 
      fill(255);
      if(frameCount%(2*delay)<delay) fill(255, 0, 0);
      rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    }
```

Comment: The question is how can I stop and restart a procedure. How to stop a "flashing" and restarting after a period of time.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of a simple timer applied to your code:

```java
int delay = 1000;// ONE SEC
int now; 
//a flag
boolean red = false;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  //start the counter
  now = millis();
}


void draw() { 
  background(96); 
  if (millis() - now > delay) { 

    //change flag
    red = !red;

    //reset counter
    now = millis();
  }


  if (red)
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  else
    fill(255);
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```